# Logic App (Read EmailID from database and send email)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Suppose I have two rows in a SQL table, with columns as Email,Record1,Record2.

Now if 'xyz@outlook.com' has two rows in table,

Email|Record1|Record2

xyz@outlook.com|Test1|Test2
xyz@outlook com|Test3|Test4

How can I send email to 'xyz@outlook.com', with 'Email Body' as , all the rows belong to that email ID.

Note: I need to read "To' in Email  as dynamic value only

Table:

Email.                            Record1.                   Record2

---

xyz@outlook.com.        Test1                        Test2

xyz@outlook.com.         Test3.                       Test4

A single email should be send to xyz@outlook com, with details in both the rows.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If the solution helps your problem, please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that, there are two rows in the table (with 3 columns as mentioned above) . I need to send one email to the EmailID ,with both the rows information.

Comment: I'm not so clear about your description. Could you please provide a screenshot of your sql table ?

Comment: Please check ,I have edited the question (see table )

Comment: Please refer to the "update" of my answer.

Comment: Okay, then what if I have multiple rows with different emaiIDs
And then I need to send all records belong to a particular emailID

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my sample below:

I have a table(named "Emails") in sql like below screenshot:

[image]

In logic app, I created an action "Get row(V2)" to get one row of the table.

[image]

Then you can use the expression `substring(body('Get_row_(V2)')?['email'], 0, indexOf(body('Get_row_(V2)')?['email'], '|'))` to get the email address `xyz@outlook.com` from `xyz@outlook.com|Test1|Test2`.

[image]

============================Update=============================

For the update of your description, pleas refer to my sample.

I have a table like below screenshot:

[image]

In logic app, I use "Get rows(V2)" to get the rows of the table.

[image]

Then use the expression `body('Get_rows_(V2)')?['value'][0]?['email']` as the value of `To` field when send email.

[image]

And in the `Body` of send email, use four expressions:

```
body('Get_rows_(V2)')?['value'][0]?['Record1']
body('Get_rows_(V2)')?['value'][0]?['Record2']
body('Get_rows_(V2)')?['value'][1]?['Record1']
body('Get_rows_(V2)')?['value'][1]?['Record2']
```